# NODE_ENV='production' doesnt not log the errors from the global error handler middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

For the exact code format, errors are logged and sent back to the client(Postman) in `development` mode. But not sent back to the client in `production` mode. This is the code for the global error handler

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // let error = { ...err };
    // if (error.name === 'CastError') error = handleCastErrorDB(error);

    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  }
};
```

**SendErorDev()**

```
const sendErrorDev = (err, res) => {
  res.status(err.statusCode).json({
    status: err.status,
    // error: err,
    message: err.message,
    // stack: err.stack,
  });
```

This is all from Jonas Node JS course which I am currently doing

Comment: Can you `console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)` and see if the value is exactly `production`?

Comment: yes its production, but even that console.log is not possible within that global error handler, i had to use the fucntion that returns the data, to set production i use this "start:prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon server.js' to run

Answer (score 0):

so apparently u are supposed to add a space after *production*  the like this

```
   `(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production ')`
```

as opposed to

```
(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
```

This error comes from package.json

start:prod": " SET NODE_ENV=production & nodemon server.js"

the space between *production* and *&* gets included in your enviroment variable. Make sure  ur write that script without including the space

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).